# How to use Visual Studio C code on other Compiler?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have seen same sample a C code, It can work on Visual Studio 2010.
I want it run on Embarcadero RAD Studio, Netbeans/MinGW, eclipse/MinGW, How can I do?
Is it can use on other Platform & Compiler(Linus/GCC, Mac/Xcode)? If yes, How to do?

dlg_three.c

```
#include <windows.h>

#include "resource.h" 

HBRUSH g_hbrBackground = NULL;

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            g_hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));

            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)LoadIcon(NULL, 
                MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION)));
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)LoadIcon(NULL, 
                MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION)));
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
        break;
        case WM_CTLCOLORDLG:    
            return (LONG)g_hbrBackground;
        case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        {
            HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
            SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            SetBkMode(hdcStatic, TRANSPARENT);
            return (LONG)g_hbrBackground;
        }
        break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDOK:
                    EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
                break;
            }
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            DeleteObject(g_hbrBackground);
        break;
        default:
            return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    return DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), NULL, DlgProc);
}
```

dlg_three.rc

```
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_CAN
#pragma code_page(1252)
#endif //_WIN32

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE DISCARDABLE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE DISCARDABLE 
BEGIN
    "#define APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS\r\n"
    "#include ""windows.h""\r\n"
    "#undef APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE DISCARDABLE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_MAIN DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 186, 46
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog tricks"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,129,7,50,14
    LTEXT           "Hi there.",IDC_STATIC,43,16,28,8
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO DISCARDABLE 
BEGIN
    IDD_MAIN, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 179
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 39
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // English (Canada) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

resource.h

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Developer Studio generated include file.
// Used by dlg_three.rc
//
#define IDC_STATIC -1
#define IDD_MAIN                        101

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        102
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1000
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: `#include <windows.h>` I'm 99% sure that this won't compile on a non-Windows machine

Comment: It should be compilable without problems with mingw on Windows.

Comment: "cross compile" -> use wine to run

Comment: If you want to write portable dialog code, use C++ and the Qt framework. I have used it successfully for a number of projects.